# How to hide an HTML form if a condition is true

Tags: php, html, pdo

Please do I hide this form (form.php) `if this condition is TRUE`. That is, I don't want the entire form to show `if this condition is TRUE`. Thanks.

```
Condition: if ($session_id == $query1){
```

**form.php**

```
 <form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden' value='<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' name="id"/></br>
 <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">
 <?php while($record = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $record['id'] ; ?>">  <?php echo $record['surname']; ?> <?php echo $record['firstname'] ; ?>  </option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </select></br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/>
 </form>
```

Comment: You have to add a CSS class that will hide the form if the condition is true.

Comment: only show the form if the condition is not met: `if(!condition){//show form}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($session_id != $query1){ 
?>
<form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden' value='<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' name="id"/></br>
 <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">
 <?php while($record = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $record['id'] ; ?>">  <?php echo $record['surname']; ?> <?php echo $record['firstname'] ; ?>  </option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </select></br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/> </div>";
 </form>
<?php
}else{

}
?>
```

It would be easier to add a class to your form.

```
<form action="tmembers.php" method="post" <?php if ($session_id == $query1){ echo 'class="hide"'; ?> >
```

And then use the following css:

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you DON'T want to show the form when this condition is `true` you need to change the operator
So this below:

```
if ($session_id == $query1) //EQUAL
```

Becomes

```
if ($session_id != $query1) //NOT EQUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

What about put the php condition on top of the form so if it's not `true` php won't render the form at all.
**PHP**

```
    <?php if ($session_id != $query1){  ?>
       <form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
         <input type="hidden' value='<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' name="id"/></br>
         <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">
         <?php while($record = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $record['id'] ; ?>">  <?php echo $record['surname']; ?> <?php echo $record['firstname'] ; ?>  </option>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
         </select></br>
         <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/> </div>";
       </form>
   <?php } ?>
```

If the condition isn't on page load, you can do some Js :

```
/*Some JS event if needed before*/
if(<?php $session_id != $query1 ?>){
 $('form').hide(); 
}
```

Comment: What if the condition changes without the page being reloaded?

Comment: then you will have to use javascript ( Or Ajax if php event is needed ) because php is compile before the page is view.

Comment: Can you explain more about your `Condition` and this will help me a lots. When do the condition is trigger ?

Comment: I'm happy your problem is solved you can check the answer if you don't have any problem. Thx you